# Showing ESRI Historical Topographic maps in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-online-basemaps

I'm trying to show a Dutch historical map (see www.topotijdreis.nl) in Openlayers. However when I load the map it tries to load the tiles but the all give a 404 error. I'm guessing it has something to do with the Projection but I can't figure it out. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
,
new ol.layer.Tile({
                   title: "1972",
                    type: "base",
                   source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                       url: 'http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/arcgis/rest/services/Historische_tijdreis_1972/MapServer/tile/{z}/{x}/{-y}'                           
                   })
                })

],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [592337.6034404513, 6824935.041410904],
        zoom: 7
    })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r9xqf86e/18/